# Why do some contracts have provisions granting a license if ownership can't be transferred?

Tags: contract-law, intellectual-property, ownership

I've seen some contracts with an ownership provision: for example if an employee invents something, it belongings to the employer.

Often times I see a provision beneath it stating "if this isn't possible, they grant us a license to do whatever we want with it".

Why would this happen? How could someone/something not be able to own something (relating to IP) in law? For whatever the reason, why would licensing be allowed?

Comment: @amon please don’t answer in comments

Comment: @DaleM I'm [no longer interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965) in writing full answers, but please feel free to flesh out these points and post your own.

Comment: @amon then just don’t comment. It’s an abuse of the commenting privilege